# proof of a statement about the Diophantine equation $ax^2-by^2=c^2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

The Diophantine equation of the form a$x^2$ – b$y^2$ = $c^2$ with ab is not a perfect square in Z has infinitely solutions in N, provided by a particular non-trivial solution in set of N.

I have racked my brains trying to think why ab not a perfect square should invalidate the proof, but can't think why.  I have many books on number theory, but none have an equation like this.

If any one can help me in this aspect...I am so thankful to them.

Comment: What is a Dio-Equation? Please consider spending more time to write up your question. Your interest is what can convince people that you have thought about that question.

Comment: $ab$ could be a perfect square, and you could still have infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @Daniel, that's not in accord with Will's answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry I didnt know that $c$ was fixed, the wording was rather confusing. I was thinking if $a=b=1$, then you could have $(x,y,c)$ being a pythagorean triple

Comment: @Daniel, OK, that clears things up. For a minute there I thought we had a proof of the inconsistency of mathematics!

Answer (score 5):

The choice of having $c^2$ on the right hand side is irrelevant, any nonzero number gives the same conclusions.

Let $$ g = \gcd(a,b). $$ By unique factorization, with
$$ \gcd \left( \frac{a}{g}, \frac{b}{g}  \right) = 1,  $$ the product being a square gives
$$  a = g \alpha^2, \; \; b = g \beta^2,   $$ and let us take $g, \alpha, \beta > 0.$
So your equation becomes
$$  c^2 = a x^2 - b y^2 = g (\alpha^2 x^2 - \beta^2 y^2) = g (\alpha x - \beta y) (\alpha x + \beta y).  $$ 
Now, either $\alpha x, \;  \beta y$ have the same  sign or opposite. With $c \neq 0$ we get get one factor at least $1$ in absolute value, so then
$$ |\alpha x| + | \beta y| \leq \frac{c^2}{g},   $$ so
$$ | x| \leq \frac{c^2}{g \alpha}   $$ and
$$ | y| \leq \frac{c^2}{g \beta},   $$
giving finiteness of the set of solutions.

MEANWHILE, if $ab$ is not a perfect square, there are infinitely many solutions to the Pell equation
$$  u^2 - a b v^2 = 1.  $$
This makes infinitely many different solutions if there are any, because
$$ a (ux + b v y)^2 - b (avx + uy)^2 = a x^2 - b y^2.     $$

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking. If you are asking for an example where $ab$ is a perfect square and the equation doesn't have infinitely many solutions, perhaps the simplest example is that with $a=b=1$.